# Add class based on contents of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add a class to a div depending on what its text contents are. The issue however I am currently having is that there is multiple containers so the same class is getting applied to all of the containers. I am pretty sure the fix for this would be to implement a proper use of "this" and maybe a loop that goes through each element with the class I am looking for but I am not sure how to implement this.

I have three types of text contents:

"Special Events" should be checked and get the special-events class.

"Daily Promotion" should get the daily-promotion class.

"Players Club Incentive" should be the incentive class.

```
var promotion = $("div.promotion-type").html();

if(promotion === "Special Event"){
    $("div.promotion-type").addClass("special-event");
}
else if(promotion === "Daily Promotion"){
    $("div.promotion-type").addClass("daily-promotion");
}
else if(promotion === "Players Club Incentive"){
    $("div.promotion-type").addClass("incentive");
}
```

I understand this is wrong. it is checking the content then adding the class to all of them. Not what I want. I just want it to check the individual container, then add the class appropriate depending on the content.

HTML sample of one of the events:

```
<li class="hidden-xs col-sm-6 col-md-4">
  <div class="calendar-event">
    <div class="event-details-container">
      <div class=" col-xs-4 calendar-thumbnail">
        <a href="/warroad-calendar/canadian-day">
          <img src="/_images/warroad/calendar/may-june-2014/canadianDay.jpg" border="0" alt="" />
        </a>
      </div>
      <h3><a href="/warroad-calendar/canadian-day">Canadian Day</a></h3>
      <h4>8 a.m. - 6 p.m.</h4>
      <strong></strong><br />
      <div class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg promotion-type">Daily Promotion</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Q8hju/

Live Page:

http://sevenclanscasino.designangler.com/warroad/warroad-calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to approach this problem.

**Try this:**

```
$("div:contains('Special Events')").addClass('special-events');
$("div:contains('Daily Promotion')").addClass('daily-promotion');
$("div:contains('Players Club Incentive')").addClass('incentive');
```

## [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8hju/1/)

**Another approach:**

```
var highlights = {
    "Special Events": "special-events",
    "Daily Promotion": "daily-promotion",
    "Players Club Incentive": "incentive"    
}

$("div.promotion-type").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass(highlights[$(this).html()]);
});
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8hju/5/)

Comment: It works for the first div, but then no classes are added to the rest of the containers on the. Is there a way to rectify this? Thanks.

Comment: It did not work because the text did not match. You had `Special Event` instead of `Special Events`. Check out my updated demo.

Comment: If there are more "types" you are going to do lots of iterations, one per "type"...

Comment: @edispring yes, that's true. My solution is definitely not great, however it is dead simple.

Comment: @martynas It's always amazing what you can do just using selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through like this - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/Q8hju/2/

```
$('div.promotion-type').each(function () {
    var promotion = $(this).html();
    console.log(promotion);
    if (promotion === "Special Event") {
        $(this).addClass("special-event"); // this is the only one with a class created for it so far
    } else if (promotion === "Daily Promotion") {
        $(this).addClass("daily-promotion");
    } else if (promotion === "Players Club Incentive") {
        $(this).addClass("incentive");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me an alternate solution based on my original code.

Comment: Be careful with `html()` to extract text.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in a loop. [fiddler example](http://jsfiddle.net/Q8hju/3/)

```
$("div.promotion-type").each(function(index, element){
    var item = $(this);
    var promotion = item.text();
    if(promotion === "Special Event"){
         item.addClass("special-event");
    }
    else if(promotion === "Daily Promotion"){
        item.addClass("daily-promotion");
    }
    else if(promotion === "Players Club Incentive"){
        item.addClass("incentive");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

martynas answer should work. I suspect this method would actually be faster to execute because you're doing fewer lookups.

```
$("div.promotion-type").each(function(i){

  var $el = $(this),
      promotion = $el.text();

  if(promotion === "Special Event"){

    $el.addClass("special-event");
  }else if(promotion === "Daily Promotion"){

    $el.addClass("daily-promotion");
  }else if(promotion === "Players Club Incentive"){

    $el.addClass("incentive");
  }
});
```